# href security, prevent xss attack

Tags: javascript, xss

```
<?PHP
//fetch website data from db..

$website=htmlentities("javascript:alert()");
?>

<a href="<?PHP echo $website;?>">Click me</a>//without http will get attack
<a href="http://<?PHP echo $website;?>">Click me</a>
```

I have a web application provide an input for user to add their website.

however i am consider the security problem, I did the testing. if I have add http:// it won't run javascript. My question is are there anything else I need to do for href security?

```
$url="example.php?name=Peter&age=37";

if(!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, FILTER_FLAG_QUERY_REQUIRED)){echo "URL is not valid";}
else{echo "URL is valid";}
```

I have use validate_url, but this one return not valid. Its from W3 example, W3 show output is valid

Comment: You should check the website before to store it in database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent XSS through an anchor `href` attribute you need to do three things:

1. Place the value inside quotes
2. Encode any characters with special meaning
3. Make sure to whitelist the protocol of the URL, if one exists

You are already doing the first two above (although [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) should be preferred over `htmlentities` for this purpose), so you only need to take care of (3). One way to do that is by brute-forcing `http://` in front of the URLs, but that would break any URL that uses a different protocol (e.g. HTTPS).

A better solution is to use a whitelist of allowed protocols, for example:

```
$allowed = [null, 'http', 'https']; // null = not specified

$scheme = parse_url($website, PHP_URL_SCHEME);
if ($scheme === false) {
    // seriously malformed URL, what to do?
}
else if (!in_array($scheme, $allowed, true)) {
    // protocol not allowed, don't display the link!
}
else {
    // everything OK
}
```

Comment: i did a testing on http to https, i put http:// "www.google.com" it will auto change  to https, however i'm not sure about others like ftp etc.

Comment: @BenWong: It won't auto-change; Google will redirect you to their secure service. If they had not set that up for your convenience, it wouldn't work at all.

Comment: this is tricky one, cause most of user they don't enter protocols, they only enter www

Comment: @BenWong: It's up to you to decide what is acceptable and what is not. `null` takes care of the "no protocol specified" case. Also, keep in mind that users may also copy-paste directly from the address bar.